# How to compile a maven project which reference to another local changed maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 projects, A and B. B is a lib project and A reference to B.
When I add new function to B, it's ok to run `mvn install` on B, but it failed on `mvn install` on A due to can not find the symbol from new B.

I'm sure I did install correctly on project B, but why A still failed to compile and install?

This is A's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>A and B's group</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>     
</dependency>
```

any clue? Thanks

Comment: Is A in your .m2/repository?

Comment: @Chris Gerken no, it's not there. But I have the source I'm just going to install it, is that related to this issue?

Comment: Why do you use **scope provided** ?

Comment: Well, unless your dependency fragment is misleading, it appears that you aren't specifying a version for your dependency on B.  Maven should complain about this when you try to run the build.  What exactly are the errors your seeing?  You say it can't find the symbol?  Which sounds like a compile error, but I don't know how it would be getting to the compile stage with out the version.  

So . . .perhaps your version is specified elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a multi-module build like the following:

```
+-- root
      +-- pom.xml
      +-- module-A
      +-- module-B
```

In the root pom you need to define the modules like this and define the packaging to **pom**.

```
<modules>
  <module>module-A</module>
  <module>module-B</module>
</modules>
```

Furthermore you can define a dependency of module-A to module -B simply by:

```
<project ..
  <parent>
     <groupId>project.parent</groupId>
     <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>module-A</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>module-B</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ..
  </dependencies>
  ..
</project>
```

With this setup you can simply build all modules from the root folder just by:

```
mvn clean package
```

or you can import that structure into Eclipse (m2e installed?) or any other IDE like IntelliJ or Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn clean install` to do a totally fresh build of A, or `mvn -U install` to force Maven to look for updated snapshots. It sounds like your environment is still using the older JAR. It's hard to tell what your setup is from this description -- sounds like you're correctly installing B to your local repository, but I'm not sure if your IDE might be trying to be 'helpful' as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `<version>` element in the project's as well as dependency's declaration.

- pass a version variable from Maven command line. Eg: `${build.version}`

Module A's `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>A & B's Group ID</groupId>
<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<version>${build.version}</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>A & B's Group ID</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>${build.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>   
...
```

So, whenever Project B is built and installed, the dependency will be available in the local maven repository for that particular version and will be picked by Project A

Comment: This will not work, You can define a version of a dependency via a property but not the artifact version.

Comment: This will make you build **not** reproducible.

Comment: You are referring to a use case scenario. This is project-specific whether you want a reproducible  build or not. And passing the same build version will indeed reproduce the build!

Comment: The problem is that you will not know the parameters you have used after 3 Years (or after 3 months or even less.). On the other hand you ignore the warnings you're getting during the run. Apart from that you can't used such things if you working with release plugin and CI systems. Furthermore a build in Maven should always build without any parameters nor activated profiles etc. to get a working build which is not the case if you define the version on command line.